# Computer is not displaying regardless of video card

Tags: display

**Resolved:** In short, issue was with TV, not with the computer. See answer below.

I'm running Windows 10 and have had no problems for almost a year on this new rig I've built. I was playing online for a couple of hours, left to run an errand and came back to a black screen. I've tried troubleshooting the problem but I can't figure it out.

### Specs:

**CPU/MOBO:** Ryzen 3700/Asus ROG strix x570-e

**Graphics Card:** Nvidia GTX 1070 then 770

**OS:** Windows 10

**Display:** LG UHD CX UHD TV via HDMI also Asus monitor via DVI-D

### Troubleshooting

1. I swapped HDMI cables
2. Hard rebooted computer
3. Removed and reinstalled video card
4. Swapped 1070 card with older 770
5. Added monitor with DVI cable
6. Remoted into computer via Unified Remote app to reinstall driver (not sure if successful)
7. Changed resolution for 770 from 4k to 1080 (tried changing refresh rate, but app wouldn't click on drop down. I don't remember if TV does anything other than 60 Hz)
8. Attempted to reboot into safe mode but not sure if successful since no display and no ability to remote
9. Checked Event Viewer for errors involving nvidia, found one on the 7th regarding failed installation (of driver I think). I don't think this is the problem since geforce said I was up to date and things were working since.

It's definitely booting into Windows since I can remote in and [slowly] do things. Also, I can't see bios splash screens or anything. The TV recognizes that something is plugged in since it's not giving its usual "no signal" message. At the same time, the nvidia control panel recognizes both displays.

I'm not sure what else I could try. Everything is new (less than a year) except for the video cards. The 1070 is 4 years old and the 770 is older (borrowed from roommate). The 770 has worked in another computer recently so it's allegedly good.

Answer (score 1):

After sleeping on it, I decided to try turning on computer one more time with no luck. I then unplugged the HDMI and connected it to my Switch and noticed that the Switch wasn't displaying either.

In my just-woken-up stupor, it occurred to me that when I unplugged the cord, the "No Signal" error didn't pop up when it definitely should have and that perhaps the issue is with the TV. I unplugged TV power and plugged it back in and boom, I am able to answer this question on my computer!

When isolating problem to the computer, don't forget to rule out *everything* with the components. I power cycled the TV by hitting power button on remote (which puts it in standby, I think) but **didn't** hard restart TV.